# How to get an element from a List with multiple data types in Spark?

Tags: scala, list, apache-spark

I know this maybe like basic question, but I searched the web still cannot find the right answer.

I have a list in Spark that looks like:

```
List[(String,Timestamp,Timestamp)]
```

I want to retrieve the second element within the first element (i.e. the first Timestamp that appears in the list above). My understanding is to use something like the following syntax:

```
a(0)(1)
```

However, it seems it's not a multi-dimensional List, so I can't use this syntax.

How to get the element I want out of this list?

Comment: you seem to have a list of a struct - what's your schema (df.printSchema)

Comment: please post the example data of the list so we can work with it and help .

Comment: `a` is a list of tuple with 3 elements. `a(0)._2` will get the second element

Comment: How are u defining this list List[(String,Timestamp,Timestamp)]? is it List[List[DataType]] ?

Comment: OP states that its not a multidimensional list - It could be nested array / lists

Comment: This data is directly got from the data frame with three different columns, so there is no pre-defined schema

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned the example list is not multidimensional, So one option to get the value can be iterating through the list.

For eg: Used below list as example

> List((StringType,DoubleType,DoubleType,IntegerType))

```
def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    val spark = SparkSession
      .builder()
      .config("spark.master", "local[1]")
      .appName("")
      .getOrCreate()

   var dataTypeList =  List((StringType,DoubleType,DoubleType,IntegerType))
   dataTypeList.map { x => println(x._2)}
}
```

Output

DoubleType

Answer (score 0):

`List[(String,Timestamp,Timestamp)]` is a list of `Tuple3`.

To get the timestamp, you should:

```
a(0)._2
```

instead of:

```
a(0)(1)
```